# Azure Search with OCR without multi-service cognitive services?

Tags: azure, computer-vision, ocr, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I want to create an `Azure Search` resource with OCR feature.

As far as i know, if you want to create OCRed documents you need to attach key to `multi-service` cognitive service:

```
"cognitiveServices": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CognitiveServicesByKey",
    "description": "xyz",
    "key": "xyz"
  },
```

But in my case, multi-service resource won't work because everyting will work under VNET and `multi-service` CCS not supporting that.

My question is, how to enrich documents in `Azure Search` with OCR wihtout using `multi-service` cognitive service? I know that i can create custom skill that will communicate with `Computer Vision` in Azure but i want to avoid writing too much code. Are there any possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can attach Azure cognitive services resource to a skillset in azure cognitive search. The procedure is explained in the below link [document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-attach-cognitive-services?tabs=portal)

The multi-service resource refers to "Cognitive Services" as the offering, rather than independent services, with access granted through a single API key. This key is specified in a skill set and allows Microsoft to charge you for using these APIs:

- Computer Vision **(Which you don't want to implement)** [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/overview)
- Language Services [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/overview)
- Translator [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/translator-overview)

These operations can be implemented using:

- **Azure Portal** `(This is suggestable approach for the current requirement)`
- **REST API**
- **.NET SDK**